# Javascript to load multi SWF file

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a situation like this. I need to repeatedly overload the single `div` with different SWF files. A folder has many `swf` files, like `sample_0.swf` `sample_1.swf` `sample_2.swf` `sample_3.swf` ... `sample_n.swf`.

Now, I want to have a single HTML file that which loads all `SWF` files one by one. In which one replacing the previously loaded object.

No need to wait until `sample_0.swf` 's completion loops to load the next file `sample_1.swf` and so on. I need to do some testing. Please help to provide a `JS` along with `HTML`.

Edit:

Please someone give me a working example

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), a js object that provides the functionality you' re asking.

Comment: I think that's not a big problem if you know how to program in any language. Take a look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation). It has about everything you want.